# What is entity-name and entity-type in Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm recently learning Apache Kafka. In the quick start tutorial, I found the following command:

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh  --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --add-config 'producer_byte_rate=1024,consumer_byte_rate=2048' --entity-name clientA --entity-type clients
```

But I can't find the explanation of these two required parameters: "entity-name" and "entity-type" in the documentation. Could someone elaborate what these are for? Where can I set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out **[the source](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConfigCommand.scala)**, you can see:

```
val entityType = parser.accepts("entity-type", "Type of entity (topics/clients)")
....
val entityName = parser.accepts("entity-name", "Name of entity (topic name/client id)")
```

So it's a switch -- you can either config topics or clients, which you reference either via topic name or client ID.